# Rosegarden - can't get it to produce any sound

Tags: daw

With zero experience of Linux, I installed Ubuntu on an old laptop and then Rosegarden. However, I've never been able to get any sound to be produced by the software - not even a metronome. I've Googled it for hours on end but to no avail. I know there are various external packages needed ("Jack"?) and I've followed all of the suggestions I've found everywhere.

Can anyone suggest some obvious reasons why a fresh install of Rosegarden would have this problem - and how can I fix it?

If you can point me to a decent tutorial I'm happy to do the necessary reading. I found the Rosegarden tutorials less than helpful in this area.

Would a reinstall do it? Did I select the wrong option at Installation and need to start again? If so, how do I uninstall and reinstall?

For info, the laptop is an HP Probook but about 7 years old, quite powerful but with, I assume, a standard sound card. It has no problem producing sound from other sources like web pages and Youtube.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminal, enter:

```
aplay -l
```

to view a list of all available sound cards.

In Rosegarden go to the "Settings" menu, and select "Manage MIDI Devices". Make sure the correct sound card is selected.

In the terminal:

```
 jack_lsp
```

to view a list of available Jack connections. If Jack is not installed, install it by running sudo apt-get install jackd2 in the terminal.

If Jack is installed:

```
ps -ef | grep jackd
```

to view a list of all Jack processes. If Jack is not running:

```
jackd -d alsa
```

If this doesn't work, uninstall Rosegarden:

```
sudo apt-get remove rosegarden
```

And reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install rosegarden
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - personally I gave-up on Rosegarden when I couldn't get it to work, but hopefully this will be helpful to someone down the line.